# AttributeError: module 'web3.geth' has no attribute 'admin'

Tags: python, api, web3py, go-ethereum

I am following the geth api documentation (https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/v5/web3.geth.html#gethadmin-api) and when running `web3.geth.admin.start_ws(host='localhost', port=8546, cors="", apis="eth, net, web3")`  getting the following error `AttributeError: module 'web3.geth' has no attribute 'admin'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used:

`from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider`

`w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))`

to connect to the local geth node and it is working fine.